# Idiomatic phrases for Major, Minor and Equal shares

Tags: idioms

I know the first one: For a major share, its "[Lion's share](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion%27s_share)."

I Don't know the terms for the other two. For equal share it was something like M(Mottley) Share.
I can't recollect.

Comment: "smaller piece of the pie" might work for less than. Certainly I've heard "splitsies" on playgrounds or "even steven" for a fair divide (although that is probably pretty dated".

Comment: If you don't like any of the answers below, you're going to have to give more context and hints for what you're looking for. *Motley share* isn't a thing.

Comment: You might be thinking of ***moiety*** for either equal share: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moiety) or smaller share: [OD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/moiety) but I wouldn't call either usage exactly *idiomatic* in the sense that *lion's share* is.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of saying each but *lion's share*, *fair share*, and *leftovers* are all fairly common.

Comment: It's worth noting: it's *the* lion's share because it's not *a* major share of something. It's *the* major share of something: i.e, more than half of everything, not more than the others' shares. For something smaller than half but more than everyone else, there's *more than ~ fair share*.

Answer (score 0):

Minor share is " The hind Quarter" or "The Dregs"

Comment: Short definition with links to sources would make a better answer.